# How to allow url redirection only if user logged in to Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to allow url-redirection (from /dl urls) only if user is logged-in to wordpress site. Otherwise don't allow. However it went "page not found" when i click these urls with or without logging in.

I've used this .htaccess code on public-html level:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dl/?$ https://external.com/directdownload- [L,R=301]
```

I expect to allow logged-in users to redirect to `https://external.com/directdownload-` links and don't allow redirection (and redirect them to login page) if they are not logged-in to wordpress.
However when i click the links which are like `https://www.example.com/dl/23434234/link.html` both logged-in and not logged-in goes to "page not found". 
How to fix?

Comment: I don't think HTACCESS is the place for this.  I think in your download page it would be much easier to check if they are logged into wordpress and then redirect them out before showing them any content.  For example `if(!get_current_user_id()) header('Location: ....');`

Comment: But thats in different server and perl based download script. I want to handle this work on wordpress and its redirect end.

Comment: Then send them to an intermediate step on that server, and redirection them out or to the perl script.  HTACCESS happens long before anything related to wordpress, so it doen't know anything about WP, or even the PHP Session really, you may be able to get the session cookie but I can't think of a way to really tell whats in it from HTACCESS

Comment: What I would do is load a slim version of Wordpress, such as with no Theme support.  Just enough to check the login stuff, then if they have a current ID they are logged in and direct them to the download server, or if they don't kick them out.  It's maybe 8 lines of PHP code.

Comment: See this post on how to load WP outside of the index.php file https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Comment: how can i do it with plain wordpress site mediator?

Comment: that link doesn't say anything for logging intermediator

Comment: No but it tells you how to load WordPress outside of index.php.  Which is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

MOD Rewrite (HTACCESS) happens way before WP is loaded so there is no way in there to tell if they are authenticated by WP or not.  You can get the Session Cookie probably, but even that is just the Session ID and there is no way to process that from HTACCESS

What I would do is create a simple PHP page, and put something like this in it (Untested).

*download.php*

```
//load WP without theme support or hooks etc.
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-load.php'); //location of this file may be different 

if(get_current_user_id()){
    //user has valid WP login session
    header('Location: {location of perl script}');
}else{
    //user is not logged in
    header('Location: {location to boot them to}');
}
exit; //just because
```

I would put this file in the same place as the index.php file for wordpress.  Because the wordpress HTACCESS has this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` basically says if this is not a real file proceed.  Because `download.php` is a real file, it will not redirect to index.php as normal.  It will just load download.php.

In download.php we load WP so there is no need to go to index.php.  This gives us total control over the code because it's outside of wordpress, but we still have access to the basic wordpress functions to check the login stuff.

Then you do a server side redirection based on if they are logged in or not.  So where I have `{location .... }` you put where you would have sent them in your HTACCESS.

Now if you need to send more data or have many download links, you can pass information the normal way you do to PHP using GET

```
   download.php?filename=somefile.txt
```

Then when you do the redirect you can use `$_GET['filename']` to aid in constructing the download path.  Be careful of the directory separator as it may allow what is called DirectoryTransversal attacks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

You can also use the URI part of the URL.

```
   download.php/somefile.txt
```

And `$_SESSION['REQUEST_URI']` but you may have to do some work to get exactly what you need.  I have no way to know what that is, so I can only make general suggestions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: to where i should put this php file?

Comment: `perl script is too complicated, not just one file many files` - you must have somepace you send them now `https://external.com/directdownload`, send them to the same place. `to where i should put this php file` anywhere, that is up to you.  Then you send them to this file (where ever it is) and adjust the paths as needed.  There is no "magic" place to put it.

Comment: is there any step by step way for doing this?

Comment: If you allow access to the pearl script from HTTP, there is no way to prevent someone from going directly there.  You could use `readfile('https://external.com/directdownload')` or CURL to download it and then give it to them in the PHP file to hide the location of it.  But it would still be accessible.  You could block it from outside your network though assuming both machines are on the same network.

Comment: `is there any step by step way for doing this?`  Yes, step 1 make file download.php, step 2. put code in that file.  step 3 run the file.....

Comment: thats easy i will put that download.php into perl script of external site but which code should i add my wp to run it? or how to implement it with perl download script?

Comment: `i will put that download.php into perl script of external site` - why would you do that.  In the wordpress HTACCESS is the rewrite rule  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` this means if not a real physical file redirect to index.php.  So on the wordpress site you can go to `example.com/download.php` provided the file exists at that location.  Then that file will load the core of wordpress which gives you access to the wordpress functions, that then allow you to check if they have a user ID, which is based on the fact they are logged in.  then you redirect them where they need to go etc..

Comment: So in the same folder as the wordpress index.php.  Put this file and then the url just have to have `download.php` and if you have your paths and URL's correct it should direct traffic where it needs to go.  As I mentioned this will not prevent direct access to the Perl script by itself, but neither would doing it in HTACCESS assuming that's possible which its not.

Comment: I don't know how sessions work in Perl but you could attempt to use the PHP Session data from wordpress within the Perl script to tell if a user is logged in or not.  But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: So basically: 1) put download.php into public-html/ 2) change all download links to /download.php 3) redirect download.php to https://external.com/directdownload- on htaccess , right?

Comment: `to external.com/directdownload- on htaccess` not this part.  The `header("Location: {url})` is a server side redirect.  So PHP will do the redirection, you'll probably never see it as it will happen pretty fast.  The problem you have is it's the order in which things are loaded.  For example User makes request, then HTACCESS runs, then Apache then PHP then Wordpress.  So you cant really know what wordpress is doing from that far above it as it doesn't even exist yet.  So there is no way to tell HTACCESS that someone is a WP logged in user because it doens't know what WP is.  Maybe with Cookie

Comment: Maybe with Cookies you could do something as they are part of the request Header, but I don't know how you would turn a Session ID (content of the cookie) into knowing they are a user from HTACCESS.  Which has the same issue as you dont have PHP to get the session data from the server etc...  The Cookie is just an ID PHP uses to pull up a file (typically) that contains the serialized session data.

Comment: note: every link is different except this part: https://external.com/directdownload-  so i have to put https://external.com/directdownload- url into : header("Location: {url}) , right? and wp-login.php to header('Location: {location to boot them to}');  ,right?

Comment: Yes, but you can pass additional data to the PHP download.php file using GET `download.php?filename=something`  or you can even use the URI  `download.php/filename` and then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get that.  And you could even hide the `download.php` part using HTACCESS but that would be a bit harder because of WP.  It may take some more coding but there is no reason you cannot pass the URL data to PHP and then have PHP decide where they go.  Without really being able to see or test it, I cant really tell you what the way to do that is, but it's possible and not terribly hard.

Comment: could u pls edit your answer and tell step by step?

Comment: tried and get the same file code when i click '''www.example.com/download.php/2n234n23/file.html''' : '''//load WP without theme support or hooks etc. define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);''' ... ...